# Sums related to the Euler totient function

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, summation, totient-function

I'm trying to estimate asymptotically the following sums:
$$
S_1(m, n) = \sum_{1\leq i \leq n, (m,i)=1}{\frac{1}{i}}
$$

$$
S_2(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n{i\phi(i)},
$$

where $(m,i) = GCD(m,i)$, and $\phi(i)$ is the [Euler totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) of $i$.

I would be grateful for any hints.

Comment: Use Möbius inversion/inclusion-exclusion on $$\sum_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant n} \frac{1}{i} = \sum_{d \mid m} \sum_{\substack{1 \leqslant i \leqslant n \\ (m,i) = d}} \frac{1}{i}.$$

Comment: @DanielFisher, I am confused how Möbius inversion could be used here. The left part of your equation depends on $n$ and the first sum of the right part is among $d|m$ (not $d|n$). In addition the sum $$\sum_{1 \leq i \leq n \\ (m,i)=d}{\frac{1}{i}}$$ is a function depending on 3 variables: $m, n, d$.

Comment: View it as an inclusion-exclusion problem. Consider $n$ fixed. Partition the set $A = \{1, 2, \dotsc, n\}$ into the sets $A_d = \{ i \in A : (m,i) = d\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I have posted this argument below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For  the first  sum, use  inclusion-exclusion and  consider the  Hasse
diagram of  the divisor poset  of $m$, with  the weights of  the nodes
$d|m$ being  $\mu(d).$ A node  $d$ here  represents the set  of values
$q\le n$ that are  multiples of $d.$ A value $q$  appears in all nodes
$d|m$ where $d|q$ and hence the total weight of a value $q$ is

$$\sum_{d|(q,m)} \mu(d).$$

This is one when $(q,m)=1$ and zero when $(q,m)\gt 1$ which means that
these weights are an exact representation of the problem. Observe that
the contribution from node $d$ is

$$\frac{1}{d} H_{\lfloor n/d\rfloor}$$

and hence

$$S_1(m, n) = \sum_{d|m} \mu(d) \frac{1}{d} H_{\lfloor n/d\rfloor}.$$

Using the dominant two terms $H_n \sim \log n + \gamma$ this becomes

$$(\log n + \gamma) \sum_{d|m} \mu(d) \frac{1}{d}
- \sum_{d|m} \mu(d) \frac{1}{d} \log d.$$

Now  for the  asymptotics with  respect to  $n$ the first is

$$(\log n + \gamma) \prod_{p|m} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$$

and we  find for  the leading  two terms  (logarithm followed  by next
term, a constant)

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{\varphi(m)}{m} \log n
+ \frac{\varphi(m)}{m} \gamma
- \sum_{d|m} \mu(d) \frac{1}{d} \log d.}$$

which is precisely as it ought  to be (initial term may be conjectured
by inspection). Note that additional terms from the expansion of $H_n$
like $H_n \sim \log n +  \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{12n^2}$ only
contribute lower  order terms,  i.e.  terms in  inverse powers  of $n$
times constants  dependent on $m,$  e.g. the  next term happens  to be
zero:

$$\sum_{d|m} \mu(d) \frac{1}{d} \frac{1}{2n/d}
=  \frac{1}{2n} \sum_{d|m} \mu(d) = 0$$

and the one after that is

$$\sum_{d|m} \mu(d) \frac{1}{d} \frac{1}{12n^2/d^2}
=  \frac{1}{12n^2} \sum_{d|m} \mu(d) d.$$

Fixing $m$ yields a bona fide asymptotic expansion in $n$.

Comment: Very well explained. A minuscule nitpick, though: the next term is zero only if $m > 1$, which isn't explicitly demanded in the question. But for $m = 1$ we just have $S_1(1,n) = H_n$ anyway, so then it's trivial.

Comment: Thank you for the kind remark. Good point about $m=1.$

Comment: We also use that $\chi(n) = 1_{gcd(n,m)=1}$ is a $m$-periodic Dirichlet character with $L(s,\chi) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi(n) n^{-s} = \zeta(s)\prod_{p| m} (1-p^{-s})$ thus $\sum_{n \le x} \frac{\chi(n)}{n} \sim Res(L(s,\chi),1) \sum_{n \le x} \frac{1}{n} \sim \log x \ \  \frac{\phi(m)}{m}$.

Answer (score 3):

You can use that $\frac{\phi(n)}{n} = \sum_{d | n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d}$  to obtain 
$$\sum_{n \le x} \frac{\phi(n)}{n} = \sum_{d \le x} \frac{\mu(d)}{d} \lfloor x/d \rfloor= x \sum_{d \le x} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^2} + \mathcal{O}(\sum_{d \le x} |\mu(d)/d|)= \frac{x}{\zeta(2)}+ \mathcal{O}(\log x)$$
which implies by summation by parts 
$$\sum_{n \le x} n \phi(n) =
x^2\sum_{n \le x}  \frac{\phi(n)}{n}+\sum_{n \le x-1} (\sum_{m \le n} \frac{\phi(m)}{m})(n^2-(n+1)^2) =
 \frac{x^3}{3 \zeta(2)} + \mathcal{O}(x^2 \log x)$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is very helpful for me. I wish I could mark two comments as answers.

Comment: @foveo what is it useful for ?

Comment: I am trying to estimate asymptotically the number of different \{0, 1\}-valued functions over integer grid which can be defined by a system of two linear inequalities. Eventually I came up with several sums involving $\phi(n)$.