# Does $\left\{\frac{p^a}{q^b}:p,q\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}=\left\{\frac{j^{\gcd(a,b)}}{k^{\gcd(a,b)}}:j,k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

How to prove $$\left\{\frac{p^a}{q^b}:p,q\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}=\left\{\frac{j^{\gcd(a,b)}}{k^{\gcd(a,b)}}:j,k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$?

First, is this identity correct?

For example if $a=1$

$$\left\{\frac{p}{q^b}:p,q\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}=\left\{\frac{j}{k}:j,k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$$

If we set $j=p$ and $k=q$

$$\left\{\frac{j}{k}:j,k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}=\left\{\frac{j(k^{b-1})}{k(k^{b-1})}\right\}=\left\{\frac{j}{k^b}:j,k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}=\left\{\frac{p}{q^b}:p,q\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$$

However, this is not a formal way of proving this case for $a=1$. I have to show

$$\left\{\frac{p}{q^b}:p,q\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\subseteq\left\{\frac{j}{k}:j,k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\} \land \left\{\frac{j}{k}:j,k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\subseteq\left\{\frac{p}{q^b}:p,q\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$$

How do I do this for $a=1$? How do I do this for $a\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Any ideas? Is my Identity correct?

Comment: Perhaps using the right tags would help. This looks like number theory, and has nothing to do with set-theory (apart from borrowing notation), proof-theory, logic or real-analysis.

Comment: My first approach would be to take arbitrary $a,b\in\Bbb N$ and $p,q\in\Bbb Z$, and try to find a suitable $j,k\in\Bbb Z$ such that ${p^a}\cdot k^{gcd(a,b)}={q^a}\cdot j^{gcd(a,b)}$. If that succeeds, you have half of the proof already. The other direction would be similar, taking arbitrary $a,b,j,k$ and finding suitable $p,q$. (I don't know if it will work, though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

The containment $\subseteq$ is easy to show.

For $\supseteq$, take any $a,b,i,j$. Let $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ be such that $ax_1+by_1=ax_2+by_2=d=\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)$ and $x_1,y_2\geq 0\geq y_1,x_2$. Take $p=i^{x_1}j^{-x_2}$, $q=i^{-y_1}j^{y_2}$. Then $p^aq^{-b}=i^{ax_1+by_1}j^{-ax_2-by_2}=i^dj^{-d}$ and you are done.

Comment: The reason I asked this question was because $\left|\left\{\frac{j^{\gcd(a,b)}}{k^{\gcd(a,b)}}:j,k\in\mathbb{Z},\gcd\left(j^{\gcd(a,b)},k^{\gcd(a,b)}\right)=1,k^{\left(\gcd(a,b)\right)}\le n\right\}\right|$ can be converted into an asymptotic series using the [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372276/how-to-derive-the-asymptotic-series-of-sums-related-to-eulers-summatory-functio) , I wanted to use this as to solve [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3356530/does-left-fracpaqbp-q-in-mathbbz-right-left-fracj-gcda-b)

Comment: I meant (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3357690/how-to-calculate-the-density-of-any-subset-of-mathbbq-using-a-particular-fo)[this]

Comment: Is my post clear? Any ideas?

Comment: My apologies, I had to take back the acceptnace mark. Just to check, if $i=7$, $j=9$, $d=1$, $a=1$ and $b=5$ what are all possible values of $p$ and $q$?

Comment: You did not ask for all possible values in your question, so I don't see why would you take back the acceptance mark... Anyway, in this case, this is easy. Since $a=1$, the possible $p$ and $q$ are given by $p=7\cdot 27\cdot c^5, q=3c$ where $c$ is a nonzero integer. In general, it is very similar. Given any $p_0,q_0$, you can generate all of them as $p(c)=\pm p_0\cdot c^b$, $q(c)=\pm q_0\cdot c^a$.

Comment: How do we determine $p_0$ and $q_0$ for any fixed $i$, $j$, $a$ and $b$? Do we just search or can we do this mathematically.

Comment: There seems to be a typo.  I think you meant $p=i^xj^{-y},\ q=i^{-y}j^x$.  I don't see how you get $p,q\in \mathbb{Z}$ though.

Comment: Oh wait.  I guess this was supposed to be the case $y\leq0\leq x$.

Comment: @saulspatz: You're right. There was a mistake: you can't just take one pair of $x,y$, you actually need two.