# How to calculate the density of any subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ using a particular Folner Sequence of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function, amenability

Suppose we choose a particular Folner Sequence of $\mathbb{Q}$ such as $F_n=\left\{\frac{p}{2^k(2q+1)}:p,q\in\mathbb{Z},k\in\mathbb{N},\gcd\left(p,2^k(2q+1)
\right)=1,2^k\le n, |2q+1| \le n, \left|\frac{p}{2^k(2q+1)}\right|\le n\right\}$? Is this a Folner Sequence of $\mathbb{Q}$?

How do we calculate the density of $A$, where $A\subseteq{\mathbb{Q}}$.

(Informally we define the density of $A$ as)

$$D(A)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left|A\cap F_n\right|}{\left|F_n\right|}$$

(Formally we use [Ultrafilters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) to replace $D(A)$ as a probability measure.)

In order to find $|A\cap F_n|$, we must present the intersection as a set with fully reduced elements. I will attempt an example but I don't know if I am correct. If I am not how do we correctly calculate the answer?

If $A=\left\{\frac{f^3}{g^6}:f,g\in\mathbb{Z},g\neq 0\right\}$ and $F_n=\left\{\frac{p}{2^k(2q+1)}:p,q\in\mathbb{Z},k\in\mathbb{N},\gcd\left(p,2^k(2q+1)
\right)=1,2^k\le n, |2q+1| \le n, \left|\frac{p}{2^k(2q+1)}\right|\le n\right\}$, the cardinality of the interesection of $F_n$ and interval $[0,1]$ is $|F_n\cap[0,1]|=\sum\limits_{|k|\le\lfloor\log_2(n) \rfloor}\sum\limits_{|q|\le\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor}\phi(2^k(2q+1))=\sum\limits_{|k|\le \lfloor \log_{2}(n) \rfloor}\phi(2^k)\sum\limits_{|q|\le \lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor}\phi(2q+1)\approx\frac{2}{\pi^2}n^2$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ using [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientSummatoryFunction.html) and $|F_n|\lessapprox(2n)\sum\limits_{q=1}^{n}\phi(q)\approx(2n)\cdot\frac{2}{\pi^2}n^2$, where $\sum\limits_{q=1}^{n}\phi(q)$ is [Euler's Summatory function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientSummatoryFunction.html). We must present $|A\cap F_n|$ in a similar way.

For example, take $A=\left\{\frac{f^3}{g^6}:f,g\in\mathbb{Z},g \neq 0\right\}$. Using the identity I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3356530/does-left-fracpaqbp-q-in-mathbbz-right-left-fracj-gcda-b), $\left\{\frac{f^3}{g^6}:f,g\in\mathbb{Z},g\neq 0\right\}=\left\{\frac{c^2}{d^2}:c,d\in\mathbb{Z}, d\neq 0\right\}=\left\{\frac{c^2}{2^{2k}(2d+1)^2}:c,d\in\mathbb{Z}, 2d+1 \le n, 2^{2k}\le n,\gcd(c^2,d^2)=1, d\neq 0\right\}$.

Using the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372276/how-to-derive-the-asymptotic-series-of-sums-related-to-eulers-summatory-functio), we can create an asymptotic series of $\left|A\cap F_n\right|=\left|\left\{\frac{c^2}{d^2}:c,d\in\mathbb{Z},\gcd(c^2,d^2)=1,d\neq 0,d^2\le n,\left|\frac{c^2}{d^2}\right|\le n\right\}\right|=F(\sqrt{n})$ where $F(n)$ is the asymptotic series of $(2n)\sum\limits_{d=1}^{\lfloor n \rfloor}\sqrt{\phi(d^2)}$. I do not understand @Reuns answer so I do not know what the asymptotic series would equal (I will call this $m(n)$). Our answer should be

$$D(A)\lessapprox\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap F_n|}{|F_n|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n)m(n)}{(2n)\frac{3}{\pi}n^3}$$

I don't what the lower bound is but am I correct so far? If not what is the lower and upper bound?

(Using [Generalized Euler's Phi Function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52718/generalized-euler-phi-function) can be helpful)

Finally, if we generalized $A$ into $\left\{\frac{s_1}{s_2}\right\}$, where $s_1:D_1\cap\mathbb{Z}\to R_1$, $s_2:D_2\cap\mathbb{Z}\to R_2$ such that $D_1,D_2$ is the domain of $s_1,s_2$ and $R_1,R_2$ is the range of $s_1,s_2$; then what is the asymptotic series of $\left|A\cap F_n \right|$? What would be the density of $A$ if we took a Folner sequence of $\left\{\sqrt[b]{\frac{p}{q}}:p,q\in\mathbb{N},q\neq 0\right\}$, where $b\in\mathbb{Q}$ is a constant variable?

Comment: Both your examples of $F_n$ seem to be infinite subsets to me...

Comment: Next what do you mean by $\sqrt[b]{\mathbb{Q}}$? you want it to be a group?

Comment: @YCor Does my post make sense now? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

> Is this a Folner Sequence of $\mathbb{Q}$?

It seems so, but this claim needs to be checked.

> $|F_n\cap[0,1]|=\sum\limits_{|k|\le\lfloor\log_2(n) \rfloor}\sum\limits_{|q|\le\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor}\phi(2^k(2q+1))$

I assume that the sets $F_n$ in the second definition are the same as these from the first definition (in the second definition we still have a condition $2q+1\le n$)

If $|2q+1|\le n$ then the bounds for $q$ should be $\lceil (–n-1)/2\rceil \le q \le \lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor$.

Also there is a double counting: if $p$ is an odd number with $\operatorname{gcd}(p,2q+1)$ then a fraction $\frac {p}{2^k(2q+1)}$ equals to a fraction $\frac {-p}{2^k(2(-q-1)+1)}$.

> $\sum\limits_{|k|\le \lfloor \log_{2}(n) \rfloor}\phi(2^k)\sum\limits_{|q|\le \lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor}\phi(2q+1)\approx\frac{2}{\pi^2}n^2$

I didn’t find at your links explicit formulae implying this equality. Assuming that $\phi(-x)=\phi(x)$ for each natural $x$, we have $\phi(2^k)=2^{k-1}$, so

$$\sum\limits_{|k|\le \lfloor \log_{2}(n) \rfloor}\phi(2^k)\approx\sum\limits_{|k|\le \lfloor \log_{2}(n) \rfloor} 2^{k-1}\approx 2\cdot 2^{\lfloor \log_{2}(n) \rfloor}$$
$$\sum\limits_{|q|\le \lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor}\phi(2q+1)\approx 2\sum\limits_{1\le q\le \lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor}\phi(2q+1)\approx $$ $$2\sum\limits_{1\le q\le \lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor}\phi(q)- 2\sum\limits_{1\le q\le \lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor}\phi(2q).$$

The first sum should be about $2\Phi(\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor)$, but the members of the second corresponding to even $q$’s should be estimated.

> If I am not correct, then how would you solve my examples? If I am incorrect how would we solve the density of my examples of $A$ using my edited Folner Sequence of $\Bbb Q$.

If I would have such a task, which looks rather technical and long, I’d *accurately* do it step by step, trying to use, if needed, some number theory results,  like properties of Totient Summatory Function, or even computational guesses, but I’m still not sure that I would be able to finish this task due to possible number theoretical complications.

*End of the update*

Too long for a comment.

> How to calculate the density of any subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ using a particular Folner Sequence of $\mathbb{Q}$?

In general it depends on given a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, a Følner sequence, and (possible) an (ultra)filter $\mathcal F$ with respect to which we take the limit (in order to assure its existence).

I tried to answer your particular question, but its formulation is so inaccurate that I failed to extract an exact and correct question :-(, so I listed my remarks below instead in order to help you to formulate such a question.

1) You regularly miss condition $q\ne 0$, when you divide by $q$.

2) The notation $F_n$ is used for sets with different definitions.

3) It cannot be $|F_n\cap[0,1]|=\frac{3}{\pi^2}n^2$, because the first quantity is integer. The same remark concerns an equality 
$|F_n|=(2n)\cdot\frac{3}{\pi^2}n^2$.

4) Even taking into account Remark 1, the sets $A=\left\{\frac{f^3}{g^6}:f,g\in\mathbb{Z}, g\ne 0\right\}$ and $B=\left\{\frac{f^2}{g^2}:f,g\in\mathbb{Z}, g\ne 0\right\}$ are not equal. For instance, a number $8=\frac {2^3}{1^6}\in A$, but it is not a square of a rational number, so it does not belong to $B$.

5) I guess that a formula $$\left|A\cap F_n\right|=\left|\left\{\frac{f^2}{g^2}:f,g\in\mathbb{Z},\gcd(f^2,g^2)=1,g^2\le n,\left|\frac{f^2}{g^2}\right|\le n\right\}\right|$$ fails for boths definitions of $F_n$, because  the first of them misses a condition $\gcd(f,g)=1$ and in the second misses a bound  $g^2\le n$.

6) If we generalize $A$ into $\left\{\frac{s_1}{s_2}\right\}$, where $s_1:D_1\to\mathbb{R}$, $s_2:D_2\to\mathbb{R}\setminus{\left\{0 \right\}}$ and $D_1,D_2\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ then $s_1$ and $s_2$ are not numbers, but functions, so elements of $A$, being quotients of functions with possible distinct domains, should be not rational numbers, but can be even undefined.

7) It is not clear why the generalized Euler Phi function for Dedekind abstract number rings or number fields pointed by a link to MathOverflow question is needed for the previous.

Comment: I edited my post; however, $|F_n \cap [0,1]|$ is the cardinality of the interesection of set $F_n$ and $[0,1]$ so a set can still exist.

Comment: @Arbuja It looks not much better, becasue whereas some issues are fixed, but some are still not. :-( In particular, $\{F_n\}$ is not a Følner sequence, because the sets $F_n$ are infinite. Maybe you want to replace in the definition of $F_n$ the condition $2q+1\le n$ by $|2q+1|\le n$. Next, in the definition of $A$, $g$ cannot be zero. And now $|F_n\cap [0,1]|$, which should be integer, is claimed equal to a strange experession $\frac{2}{\pi^2}(n)n^2$.

Comment: I edited everything except $|F_n\cap[0,1]|\approx \frac{2}{\pi}n^2$. Note my expression, $\frac{2}{\pi}n^2$ is defined for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $F_n$ has more elements as $n$ so aprroximating $|F_n\cap[0,1]|$ in terms of $n$ makes sense. If I am not correct, then how would you solve my examples?

Comment: AlexRavsky I meant to say $F_n$ has more elements as $n$ grows larger so approximating $|F_n|$ in terms of $n$ makes sense. If I am incorrect how would we solve the density of my examples of $A$ using my edited Folner Sequence of $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @Arbuja I updated my answer.

Comment: I’m still not satisfied with the answer. Does [@Reuns answer in this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372276/how-to-derive-the-asymptotic-series-of-sums-related-to-eulers-summatory-functio) give you any ideas to solving my examples?