# How to find two integers in an identity of two sets?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

Suppose we have sets on both equalities.....

$$\left\{\frac{i^{\gcd(a,b)}}{j^{\gcd(a,b)}}:i,j\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}=\left\{\frac{p^{a}}{q^{b}}:p,q\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$$

For fixed $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$

What would be the values of $p$ and $q$ when $i$ and $j$ Is fixed?

It seems the answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3356530/does-left-fracpaqbp-q-in-mathbbz-right-left-fracj-gcda-b) would not work.

For example if $a=1$, $b=5$, $i=2$, $j=3$, the answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3356530/does-left-fracpaqbp-q-in-mathbbz-right-left-fracj-gcda-b) states that $x+5y=1$ so “I assume” $x$ can equal $-4$ while $y$ can equal $1$ hence $p=2^{1} 3^{4}=162$ and $q^5=(2^{4} 3^{1})^5$ since $p/q \neq {2/3}$ we can conclude the proof does not help us solve our problem.

What can we use instead? Any hints?

Comment: There's a typo in that answer, which I just noted on the linked question.  There seems to be a more basic problem, which I also noted.

Comment: Actually, I think the answer given there had two typos, which offset when both are corrected.  Make the corrections I suggested there, and I think things will work.

Comment: This question is best answered in the other post.  We can essentially close this as a duplicate or obsolete.